# Optimize a PHP / MySQL script to reduce server usage

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, ads, banner

I have a website with more than 1'000'000 daily pageview and a php script to display 2-3 banner ads on each page and count impressions

**To count the impressions, after each banner there is an image:**

`<img src="https://example.com/impression.php?client=ABC&banner=XYZ" width=1 height=1>`

**This is an example of the impression script:**

```
require('global.php'); // connect to mysql, read default settings, etc

if( isset( $_GET['client'] ) ) && !empty( $_GET['client'] ) ) { $client = secure( $_GET['client'] ); } else { die('error param'); }
if( isset( $_GET['banner'] ) ) && !empty( $_GET['banner'] ) ) { $banner = secure( $_GET['banner'] ); } else { die('error param'); }

$check_client = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT id FROM clients WHERE id = '$client' AND status = 1 LIMIT 1" ) or die( 'error mysql' );
if( mysqli_num_rows( $check_client ) == 0 ) { die('error client'); }

$check_banner = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT campaign_id FROM banners WHERE id = '$banner' AND status = 1 LIMIT 1" ) or die( 'error mysql' );
if( mysqli_num_rows( $check_banner ) == 0 ) { die('error banner'); }    
$read_campaign_id = mysqli_fetch_array( $check_banner ); 

$check_campaign = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT id FROM campaigns WHERE id = '$read_campaign_id[0]' AND status = 1 LIMIT 1" ) or die( 'error mysql' );
if( mysqli_num_rows( $check_campaign ) == 0 ) { die('error campaign' );  }

$check_unique = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT id FROM impressions WHERE datetime LIKE '$today%' AND banner = '$banner' AND ip = '$ip' ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1" ) or die( 'error mysql');
if( mysqli_num_rows( $check_unique ) == 1 ) { $unique = 0; } else { $unique = 1; }

mysqli_query( $con, "INSERT INTO impressions ( client, campaign, banner, datetime, unique, ip, page ) VALUES ( '$client', '$read_campaign_id[0]', '$banner', '$now', '$unique', '$ip', '$url' )" ) or die( 'error mysql' );

header( 'Content-type: image/png' );
header( $path . '/img/pixel.png' );
mysqli_close( $con );
exit;
```

In this case what is the **best way** to optimize the script and reduce resources usage and concurrent connections on my server?

- For example its possible to join some mysql query in one single query? I think should be much faster, but I'm not sure...
- Another possible way could be to save the impressions in a CSV file, and every 2-5 min import this file on mysql? but it only save 1 query...

**EDIT:**
This is the mysql table structure (only with the useful fields for this example)
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ffe3/1

Comment: First make sure all of your MySQL queries are optimized. Check them using `EXPLAIN` queries.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the impressions table in particular?

Comment: @Mark Baker: All the **id** columns are primary. **datetime** (in impressions table) is an index. **campaign_id** in the banners table and **client, campaign, banner** in the impressions table have a Foreign key constraints on update, so i think they are automatically indexes

Comment: I suspect you can get this down to 1 - 3 queries as opposed to 5. If you can post a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of these or create an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) it would be easier for us to make recommendations and help.

Comment: Instead of "save to CSV" why not parse the apache log files ? They have all of the info you need ? theres nothing session based here

Comment: @prodigitalson sure, just added a sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run all the selects in a single query.

Rather confusingly (as you only require one row from each, and there is no obvious relation between them) you can do this with a cartesian product.

Your schema sucks (WHERE datetime LIKE '$today%' using a string to store a date!!!!)

Why are you ordering the result of $check_unique when you only want to see if any row exists?

```
SELECT clients.id AS client_id
, banner.campaign_id AS banner_campaign_id
, campaign_id
,(SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM impressions 
   WHERE impressions.datetime LIKE '$today%' 
   AND impressions.banner = '$banner' 
   AND ip = '$ip' 
   LIMIT 1) AS check_unique
FROM clients
INNER JOIN banners
INNER JOIN campaigns
WHERE clients.id = '$client' AND clients.status = 1
AND banners.id = '$banner' AND banners.status = 1
AND campaigns.id = '$read_campaign_id[0]' AND campaigns.status = 1
LIMIT 1
```

Alternatively you could unroll it into a UNION but that's much less fun.

Comment: Thx! The column "datetime" is a datetime type `datetime datetime NOT NULL` why it sucks? I use `ORDER BY datetime DESC` because the check is $today, to avoid that mysql read old records, is not better?

Comment: Then your query sucks - should be a range operation with any implicit cast on the literals.